# Cannot connect logstash pipeline to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

My logstash pipeline is:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "foo"
        path => "/usr/share/logstash/logs/server.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://develk_es:9200"]
    }
}
```

It gives the error:

> [2017-05-13T06:05:10,295][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"the scheme http does not accept registry part: develk_es:9200 (or bad hostname?)"}

Removing that pipeline and letting logstash use the default, I can access the es endpoint successfully:

```
bash-4.2$ curl http://develk_es:9200
{
  "name" : "5HOR2_o",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "IUTpsvdGQoqDqZTEhZtWsw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.0",
    "build_hash" : "780f8c4",
    "build_date" : "2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Which makes sense as they are both on the same network:

```
$ docker network inspect netelk
[
    {
        "Name": "netelk",
        "Id": "bd5fdfda89bafd742b535974be8463a828bf6f7f0dbe0b9234be7147953fee1e",
        "Created": "2017-05-13T06:07:21.542334809Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {
            "01449553f056f70bc955fdd38970147ec1c6cff8afe7ba12ef4afcd02666290c": {
                "Name": "develk_ls",
                "EndpointID": "5c2b36ff64411560a9aeb63a4004c4e1b0c9f31eafb6b82e51967eac7f138ce9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e16b996ed1bb8e3f6082e3f0f83b8625a6ced801968dfd38e4a3753a60e98719": {
                "Name": "develk_es",
                "EndpointID": "a2ded2cc5988c3d9ee37ef8e0ffa2075fdaff5bb61b0e434552d20241b3b0515",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

How do I make logstash connect to ES?

Comment: Try only with `hosts => ["develk_es:9200"]`

Comment: @AndreiStefan I have and that also doesn't work. Also tried with just the name, no luck. It must be the docker network setup?

Comment: Most likely, but my docker skills are close to 0 and can't help you :-(.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you try replacing `develk_es` with the IPv4 address of that box instead?

Comment: Have you tried with `hosts => ["https://develk_es:9200"]`? Did you also tried setting an index with `index => "my-test-index"`? What suggested by @AndreiStefan should work though (for the hostname)

Comment: @AndreaRomagnoli it was the underscore. I just removed it, but I think it should be escaped. I recall it being in the docs somewhere, but I can't find it to answer

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie Good catch! Thanks for sharing with us your solution

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie It's not just in the docs, it's in the DNS RFC. Underscores are not valid characters in hostnames and you shouldn't use them.

Comment: If both are in same network use that network name -> netelk. try hosts => ["netelk:9200"]

Comment: curl http://develk_es:9200 Is working from logstash ?